# How to divert a thread to post messages to a new window

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mfc

I have a thread that I pass an HWND of a window where it post messages and updates a progress bar. The user can however go to another window (modal) where I would also like to show the progress of this thread. Passing the initial HWND is obviously straight forward but how can I divert the thread to post messages to the new window once its running? This is a c++ worker thread. I am using Windows 7,MFC, C++.

Answer (score 0):

Put it other way around.  Let progress windows get the address of the class from worker thread, and ask it periodically for progress.  With timer, for example.  That way, you will be able to have as much progress windows as you need.

Comment: interesting thought but the worker thread doesn't have GUI. How can I ask address of the class and what does that class do?

Comment: I like this solution better. The progress bar code should know about what it's measuring, not the other way around. @zadane, Just pass the address of a function (or other callable object) to call to receive the progress.

Comment: @zadane By the same mechanism you gave the thread the HWND you can give it a pointer to the class instead.

Comment: This still leaves something to be desired. I have a clock running in the thread but this approach requires me to run timer in the dialog as well, that would seems like code duplication. If I have to use timer than I shouldn't be needing a separate thread. Perhaps I didn't put this detail in OP, my thread only waits for a certain amount of time and notify the GUI. Maybe I will repost the question with that detail.

Comment: If by using timer you would be able to lose thread, do it, by all means.  BTW, since you are using MFC, there is no need to pass HWND around, every window has its class.

Comment: However, I just re-read the question - you can't do it in the timer, since you need 2 windows to show the progress.  Clearly, proper way is to have worker thread doing stuff, and UI elements (windows) asking it for progress periodically.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches. One is Daniel's way, that polls progress info from the UI window. All you need is a thread-safe 'int GetProgressPercent() const' member in the thread-implementing class (or equivalent free function).

The other approach is to use PostMessage or PostThreadMessage in the worker thread as progress happens and on the other end process the message adjusting the bar.

The main problem with either is to handle lifetime issues, prevent calls to object or HWND when it is actually gone already.  For that the PostThreadMessage way is probably the safest baseline, as the main thread is supposed to be there and manage all the other threads -- and track the overall state of the program able to do meaningful dispatch to live windows or nothing. But it's the most complex too.